# What is the minimal polynomial of $a$ over $\Bbb K$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, minimal-polynomials

I am studying algebraic elements over a field. The context started with the following discussions $:$

Let $\Bbb K$ be a field. Let $A$ be a $\Bbb K$-algebra. An element $x \in A$ is called algebraic over $\Bbb K$ if the substitution homomorphism $$\varepsilon_x : \Bbb K[X] \longrightarrow A$$ defined by $F(X) \mapsto F(x)$ has a non-zero kernel i.e. $\exists$ some non-constant polynomial $F \in \Bbb K[X]$ such that $F(x)=0.$ Since $\Bbb K$ is a field, $\Bbb K[X]$ ( the polynomial ring over $\Bbb K$ ) is a PID. So $Ker\ (\varepsilon_x)$ being an ideal of $\Bbb K[X]$ is principal. Therefore $\exists$ a unique non-constant monic polynomial $\mu_x \in \Bbb K[X]$ such that $Ker\ (\varepsilon_x) = \left \langle \mu_x \right \rangle.$ $\mu_x$ is called the minimal polynomial of $x$ over $\Bbb K.$ So by the first isomorphism theorem $\exists$ a $\Bbb K$-algebra isomorphism between $\Bbb K[X]/\langle \mu_x \rangle$ and $\text {Im}\ (\varepsilon_x) = \Bbb K [x]$ i.e. $$\Bbb K[X]/\langle \mu_x \rangle \cong \Bbb K[x].$$ Since $\Bbb K$-algebra isomorphisms are also $\Bbb K$-vector space isomorphism so we can say that $$\text {Dim}_{\Bbb K} \left (\Bbb K[X] / \langle \mu_x \rangle \right ) =  \text{Dim}_{\Bbb K}\left (\Bbb K[x] \right ).$$  But we know that $$\text {Dim}_{\Bbb K} \left (\Bbb K[X] / \langle \mu_x \rangle \right ) = \text{deg} \left (\mu_x \right ).$$ So we have $$\text{Dim}_{\Bbb K} \left (\Bbb K[x] \right ) = \text{deg} \left (\mu_x \right ).$$

Now for any $x \in A,$ $\Bbb K[x]$ is a $\Bbb K$-subalgebra of $A.$ So in particular if $A$ is a finite dimensional $\Bbb K$-algebra then $\Bbb K[x]$ is also a finite dimensional $\Bbb K$-subalgebra of $A.$ Therefore for any $x \in A$ we have $$\text{Dim}_{\Bbb K} \left (\Bbb K[x] \right ) < \infty.$$ Therefore for any $x \in A$ $$\text {deg} \left (\mu_x \right) < \infty.$$

This shows that if $A$ is a finite dimensional $\Bbb K$-algebra then every element of $A$ is algebraic over $\Bbb K.$

Now $\Bbb K^n$ is a finite dimensional $\Bbb K$-algebra. Let $a=(a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_n) \in \Bbb K^n.$ Then by our previous discussions it is quite clear that $a$ should be algebraic over $\Bbb K.$ Then my question is $:$

**How do I find out the minimal polynomial of $a$ over $\Bbb K$**?

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: I think there is no general algorithm to achieve this.

Comment: To me $\mathbb{K}^n$ is a vector space, not an algebra.  How are you defining multiplication on $\mathbb{K}^n?$  ... perhaps element-wise?  And, related, what is the image of $\mathbb{K}$ inside $\mathbb{K}^n?$

Comment: The minimal polynomial of $a \in $ the $K$-algebra $ K^n$ is just $\prod_{b\in \{ a_j\}} (X-b)$, more interesting is when we put another $K$-algebra structure on the $K$-vector space $K^n$, and when we look at the minimal polynomials of elements of $M_n(K)$ a $K$-algebra containing all the degree $\le n$ extensions of $K$

Comment: But @reuns how does an $n$-tuple $(a_1,a_2, \cdots , a_n)$ be a zero of a polynomial in one single variable $X$? It should satisfy a polynomial in $K[X_1,X_2, \cdots, X_n].$ Isn't it so?

Comment: If $P(X) \in K[X]$ and $a \in K^n$ then $P(a) = (P(a_1),\ldots,P(a_n)) \in K^n$ and it is $0\in K^n$ iff $P$ has all the $a_j$ in its roots.  The generalization is [Caley-Hamilton theorem](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th%C3%A9or%C3%A8me_de_Cayley-Hamilton).

Comment: @Brian Moehring I am defining component wise scalar multiplication of the elements of $\Bbb K^n$ with the elements of the field $\Bbb K.$ Then that scalar multiplication is compatible with the addition and multiplication in $\Bbb K^n.$

Comment: Oh! I can see now @reuns. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think that you define $P(a) : = (P(a_1),P(a_2),\cdots, P(a_n)).$ Am I right @reuns?

Comment: No, for a unital $K$-algebra $A$ I define $P(X) = \sum_{m=0}^M c_m X^m \in K[X], P(a)= \sum_{m=0}^M c_m a^m \in A$ if $A = K^n$ then $a=(a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_n), P(a) : = (P(a_1),P(a_2),\cdots, P(a_n))$. That $A$ is a unital $K$-algebra means that the map $P(X,Y) \mapsto P(a,b)$ is a ring homomorphism $K[X,Y] \to A$ which is the identity on $K$ for all $a\in A$.

Comment: I meant $P(X) \mapsto P(a)$ for all $a \in A$

Comment: That's exactly what I have said @reuns in my first comment above. But the definition in my book is wrongly described then I guess. The domain of the map $\varepsilon_x$ is depending upon the dimension of $A$ as a vector space over $\Bbb K.$

Comment: @mathmaniac. Note that scalar multiplication is defined canonically on $\mathbb{K}^n,$ so that wasn't what I was talking about.  The problem is that multiplication of two elements of $\mathbb{K}^n$ is not canonically defined, nor is the injective map $\mathbb{K} \hookrightarrow \mathbb{K}^n,$ both of which are necessary to define $\mathbb{K}^n$ as a $\mathbb{K}$-algebra.

Comment: What do you mean by the statement "multiplication of two elements in $\Bbb K^n$ is not canonically defined" @Brian Moehring?

Comment: For instance $\mathbb{C} \cong \mathbb{R}^2$ as an $\mathbb{R}$-vector space with canonical ordered basis $1, i,$ but with respect to this basis $\mathbb{R} \hookrightarrow \mathbb{R}^2 : x \mapsto (x,0)$ and $(a,b)\cdot (c,d) = (ac-bd, ad+bc),$ which obviously imbues $\mathbb{R}^2$ with a different $\mathbb{R}$-algebra structure than had we defined $(a,b)\cdot(c,d) = (ac,bd)$ and $x \mapsto (x,x)$

Answer (score 1):

If you put just the "direct product of unital rings" algebra structure on $K^n$, then the minimal polynomial is the minimal monic one that has each of the $a_i$ as root; this is so by definition, since the evaluation of the polynomial in $(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$ is just the $n$-tuple of evaluations in each of the $a_i$. As mentioned in one of the comments, this polynomial can be written as $\prod_{b\in\{ a_1,\ldots,a_n\}}(X-b)$ (its degree is the number of *distinct* values among the$~a_i$).

Comment: By the way, there is no reason to write "$\Bbb K$"; this is not any reserved meaning of the symbol $K$, as it is just being used as a variable to denote some field.